# Google 301 redirect does not seem to work

Tags: mod-rewrite, seo

Google has spidered some pages that are now available on some other website so I have implemented a 301 redirect. I have verified by manually entering some of the URLs that the user is in fact redirected to the new website.

However, the GoogleBot is still trying to access the old URLs over and over. The redirect rules are in place for more than one year now. It seems that the 301 redirect has no effect for Google. Same thing with the Yahoo spider.

Here is my VirtualHost entry. The rewrite rule redirects all requests matching the three patterns to the new website.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  <Directory /home/web0000/www>
    Options FollowSymLinks Indexes ExecCGI
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    AllowOverride All
  </Directory>
  CustomLog "|/opt/httpd/bin/rotatelogs -l /home/web0000/log/access_log.%Y-%m-%d-%H_%M_%S 86400"  combined
  ErrorLog  "|/opt/httpd/bin/rotatelogs -l /home/web0000/log/error_log.%Y-%m-%d-%H_%M_%S 86400"
  DocumentRoot /home/web0000/www
  ServerAdmin admin@mydomain.de
  ServerName www.myolddomain.de
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/de/.* [OR]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/en/.* [OR]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/es/.*
  RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.mynewdomain$1 [R=301,L]
</VirtualHost>
```

Here is a sample log file entry:

```
www.myolddomain.de 66.249.66.217 - - [17/Jun/2011:15:21:55 +0200] 
"GET /de/kontakt.html HTTP/1.1" 301 294 "-" 
"Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
```

Please advise how to do the redirect so that Google eventually learns about the change.

Comment: The more important question is whether when searching for the relevant content, the results show the new or old URLs. Remember that the spider's job is to find things for the index to index. Presumably even though it's finding these URLs, it's not passing them on to the indexer because you've told it the content has moved permanently. If you've had permanent redirects in place for a year, and no one other than bots is hitting the old URLs, you can probably retire them. All of which is speculation and so I'm commenting rather than answering. :-)

Comment: If there are any links to these pages (either from your own site or from external ones), robots will hit these URLs forever. As TJ said, as long as the right URLs are appearing in the search listings you don't have anything to worry about.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you actually give to the spyder a 301 header for the page (make some test).

The most important thing have your serp clear from these Urls. You should be able also to remove such URLs in Google Web Master Tool.